# how to get each item without using a loop from string array in c#

Tags: c#

Iam using  3 string arrays.i want to get each item corresponds to the index,ie if itnme will have the second item,then i need to get second item from other two string arrays such as qntity,price.How can i possible this?

```
    string[] itmnme= new string[0] { };
    string[] price= new string[0] { };
    string[] qntity= new string[0] { };
foreach (string iname in itmnme)
  {
    foreach (string qnt in qntity)
      {
        foreach (string prc in price)
          {
          }
      }
  }
```

Comment: could you please include three example lists?

Comment: @un-lucky:string[] itmnme= new string[0] { };
        string[] price= new string[0] { };
        string[] qntity= new string[0] { };

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the size of all your arrays is identical you can use such code:

```
for(int i=0; i<itmnme.Length; i++)
{
    var name = itmnme[i];
    var quantity = qntity[i];
    var price = price[i];
    // do what you need with these values
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the best way that you can adopt is, using List Of Classes:

```
 public class Product
    {
        public string itmnme;
        public string price;
        public string qntity;
    }
```

Your List will be like :

```
 List<Product> productList = new List<Product>{new Product()
                       {itmnme="item1",price="20",qntity="1"}, 
                       new Product(){itmnme="item2",price="220",qntity="3"} };
```

So that you can Iterate the List and easily get value from the List:

```
        foreach (var item in productList)
        {
            string itmnme=item.itmnme;
            string price = item.price;
            string qntity=item.qntity; 
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you will need to retrieve data from each array, given a position, is that right? If so you can have a method like:

```
public string[] getItemAtPosition(int position)
{
    string[] dataResult = new string[0]{};

    string itmnmeItem = itmnme[position];
    string qntityItem = qntity[position];
    string priceItem = price[position];

    dataResult.add(itmnmeItem);
    dataResult.add(qntityItem);
    dataResult.add(priceItem);

    return dataResult;
    //now this array contains data from each array at the specified position

}
```